# Uniswap V3 Pool Token with Sell Taxes

Tags: solidity, tokens, uniswap, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3

Working on a new Token contract using a V3 Uniswap pool for Liquidity.

The ERC20 token has the traditional taxes (reflection, buy,sell etc.)

It seems that it's not possible to have a token with tax on Sells when using Uniswap V3 Liquidity Pools.

The sells work on wallets that are Excluded from Fees and there is no issues however a wallet that would be impacted by the Sell Tax isn't able to process a sale. Have tried setting the slippage to well above the Tax amount but still fail.

Picture of the Error Message displayed in Uniswap.

This testing is being done on Goerli TestNet however since it's a fork of MainNet I'm sure the same issue would be present on the MainNet.

What do people do with tokens that have Taxes and want to use V3 LP. There has to be some solution since they are encouraging people to mover over to and use V3?

[image: Uniswap V3 Sell with Sell Taxes]